# Confusion between Pointer Notation and Dot Notation in Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to make all the names in the Struct lowercase so that I can compare them and remove them.

```
int removeNameCard(NameCard *idCard, int *size){
    char name[80];
    char *ptr;
    char rubbish;
    int a = 0, c = 0;
    printf("removeNameCard():\n");
    printf("Enter personName:\n");
    scanf("%c", &rubbish); // Why is there a '\n' char here??
    fgets(name, 80, stdin);
    if((ptr = strchr(name, '\n'))){
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
    if((*size) == 0){
        printf("The name card holder is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Convert everything to Lower Case first
    while(name[a]){
        name[a] = tolower(name[a]);
        a += 1;
    }
    printf("tolower(): %s", name);
    for(int b = 0; b < *size; b += 1){
        // Why is this Dot Notation when I passed in a pointer to the Struct?
        while (idCard[b].personName)[c]){
            (idCard[b].personName)[c] = tolower((idCard[b].personName)[c]);
            c += 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < *size; i += 1){
        if((idCard[i].personName) == name){
                                    printf("%d. This is from Holder: %s, This is from User: %s", i,(idCard[i].personName),name);
            printf("The name card is removed\n");
            printf("nameCardID: %d\n", idCard[i].nameCardID);
            printf("personName: %s\n", idCard[i].personName);
            printf("companyName: %s\n", idCard[i].companyName);
            int k = 0;
            do{
                idCard[i+k].nameCardID = idCard[i+k+1].nameCardID;
                strcpy((idCard[i+k].personName),(idCard[i+k+1].personName));
                strcpy((idCard[i+k].companyName),(idCard[i+k+1].companyName));
            }while((i+k+1) != (*size + 1));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am rather confused why the Compiler asked me to use Dot Notation instead of Pointer Notation as I thought I passed in the address of the Struct into *idCard so it should be a pointer if I am not wrong?

And am I wrong for trying to access each individual character in every name of the Struct like this?:
(idCard[b].personName)[c]

Thank you

Comment: I can't help to think that your [mre] could be even more minimal.

Comment: If `idCard` is an array of `NameCard` structures, then `idCard[b]` is such an `NameCard` structure *object*. `idCard[b]` is not a pointer to a structure (where the "arrow" operator `->` would be used). That's why the "dot" operator`.` should be used in `idCard[b].personName`.

Comment: Also you don't need parentheses for `(idCard[b].personName)[c]`, `idCard[b].personName[c]` works just as well.

Comment: BTW: `if((idCard[i].personName) == name){` is not the way to compare strings,

Comment: @Antoine Yes, it has helped me greatly in understanding the reasons for both operators to exist, although I would probably have to code more to fully appreciate what the comment has explained in full. Thank you so much, I have learnt a lot :>

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sorry for my poor post. Thank you for sharing wif me the guidelines on how I can post better, I will check it out!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see!! I have mistakenly thought that ```idCard[b]``` to be a pointer. However, I was wondering when I pass ```idCard[b]``` into a helper function that takes a pointer to a struct, does it automatically reduce ```idCard[b]``` to a pointer as I seem to recall reading about it being the case like this

Comment: @wildplasser thank you!! I have a bad habit of doing that when I am supposed to be using strcmp().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am rather confused why the Compiler asked me to use Dot Notation instead of Pointer Notation…

`idCard[i]` is a structure, not a pointer to a structure, so its members are accessed as `idCard[i].member`, not `idCard[i]->member`.

`idCard[i]` is a structure because whenever `x` is a pointer, `x[i]` is one of the objects that `x` points to. It is not the address of the object. You could calculate the address of the object with `x+i`, and then you could reference the object with `*(x+i)`. And `x[i]` is actually defined in this way; `x[i]` is defined to be `*(x+i)`. (In case of expressions generally, `E1[E2]` is defined to be `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.)

> And am I wrong for trying to access each individual character in every name of the Struct like this?: (idCard[b].personName)[c]

This will work, but the parentheses are unnecessary. You can use `idCard[b].personName[c]`. Due to the C grammar, it is already grouped as `(idCard[b].personName)[c]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications. However, I am still a bit confused. Do you mean that if ```x``` is a pointer to a Struct, it would have the same members as the Struct, which is why it can point to various objects using ```x[i]```?

Comment: Apologies but why will ```x+i``` give me the address of the object? I was under the impression that pointers will point to the first member of a Struct if I did not specify which member/object to specifically point to? Thank you very much

Comment: @Michelin_Boi: If `x` is a pointer to a structure, it does not have any members. A pointer just points to a place in memory; it does not contain members. If `x` is a pointer to a structure, then `*x` refers to that structure. So `*x` is that structure, and `*x` has members. So `(*x).personName` is a member. Also, `x[0]` is the same structure as `*x`, so `x[0].personName` is a member.

Comment: @Michelin_Boi: `x+i` uses address arithmetic. If we have an array of structures, say array `A`, and the type of `x` is a pointer to that type of structure, then we can make `x` point to any element of the array. For example, `x = &A[3];` sets `x` to point to `A[3]`. The rule for address arithmetic is that, if `x` points to element `A[t]`, then `x+i` calculates a pointer that points to `A[t+i]`. After `x = &A[3];`, then `x+2` points to `A[5]`. Thus, if `x` points to `A[0]`, then `x+i` points to `A[0+i]`, which equals `A[i]`. So `x+i` points to `A[i]`, and `*(x+i)` **is** `A[i]`.

Comment: Ohhhh I see, it makes so much sense now!!! thank you so much for taking the time to explain to me!! :>

Answer (score -1):

> However, I am rather confused why the Compiler asked me to use Dot Notation instead of Pointer Notation as I thought I passed in the address of the Struct into *idCard so it should be a pointer if I am not wrong?

Arrays are mostly just pointers to the first element in the array (except that the compiler may be aware of the array size).

Because arrays are mostly just pointers; for arrays of integers `myInt = myIntArray[x];` is like `myInt = *(myIntArray + x);` - the **pointer dereferencing is implied by array indexing**. Note that to access a `char` in the middle of an `int` in an array, you could (not portably) use something like `myChar = *((char *)(myIntArray + x)) + offset_of_char_in_int);`; and this is a little bit like accessing a field inside an array of structures (in that they're both accessing something smaller within an array of larger things).

For arrays of structures; indexing the array causes dereferencing (just like it does for the array of integers); so `myIDcardStruct = idCard[i];` is like `myIDcardStruct = *(idcard + i);`. Because array indexing has implied dereferencing, `myIDcardStruct` is not a pointer.

The `->` operator is like adding the offset of the requested structure's field to the address, casting the address to the requested field's type, and then dereferencing. In other words `myInt = myStructPointer->myIntField;` is like `myInt = (*myStructPointer).myIntField;` which is like `tempAddress = (void *)myStructPointer + offset_of_myIntField; myInt = *((int *)tempAddress);`.

What this means is that if you have an array of structures (which is mostly a pointer to the first structure in the array), indexing the array causes the pointer to be implicitly dereferenced, and using `->` also causes implicit dereferencing; and if you do both then you've (implicitly) dereferenced a pointer twice, which is too much dereferencing (because it's not a pointer to a pointer to a structure, or an array of pointers to structures). Because you only want it dereferenced once you have to choose between one implicit deference (array indexing) or the other implicit dereference (`->`); e.g. you can choose between `myInt = idCard[i].nameCardID;` or `myInt = (idCard + i)->nameCardID;`.

Of course the important thing is making code easy to read, and `myInt = idCard[i].nameCardID;` is easier to read than `myInt = (idCard + i)->nameCardID;`.

Comment: We continually have to correct the notion that “arrays are pointers”, and writing “Arrays are mostly just pointers” does damage to that effort. It should not be in this answer. It is sufficient to explain that `idCard[i]` is a structure object, not a pointer to it, and therefore a member of the structure is accessed with `idCard[i].member`, not `idCard[i]->member`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That effort is misguided (does more harm than good, especially when people are trying to understand what their code actually asks the CPU/hardware to do), and deserves damage.

Comment: I have never thought about Arrays like this before and I don't think I fully understood everything. However, I thought it was an informative read and I will try to refer to both answers as I code more in the future!! Thank you :>